# Finding the last index of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

How do you retrieve the last element of an array in C#?

Comment: are you looking for how to retrieve the value stored in the last spot of the array, or the actual value of the index?

Comment: i mean the index value, that is, started from 0 to n

Comment: The title and content ask different questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the first and last item of an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387396/get-the-first-and-last-item-of-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The array has a `Length` property that will give you the length of the array. Since the array indices are zero-based, the last item will be at `Length - 1`.

```
string[] items = GetAllItems();
string lastItem = items[items.Length - 1];
int arrayLength = array.Length;
```

When declaring an array in C#, the number you give is the length of the array:

```
string[] items = new string[5]; // five items, index ranging from 0 to 4.
```

Comment: This fails when the array has zero items, in which case `(items.Length - 1) == -1`

Comment: In C# 8 there is a new operator for indexing:
`char[] arr = {'c', 'b', 'a'};   int a_last = arr[^1];   int b_second_last = arr[^2];`

Answer (score 174):

LINQ provides [Last()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx):

```
csharp> int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
csharp> nums.Last();              
5
```

This is handy when you don't want to make a variable unnecessarily.

```
string lastName = "Abraham Lincoln".Split().Last();
```

Comment: Last is nice but it is very specific to get only the last item. Does C# have something like slice that can be used like `slice(-2)` to get the last 2 or `slice(0,-2)` to get items from the start except the last 2? Then a function like Last would not be needed as one could just do `slice(-1)` as I'm used to do in other languages.

Comment: @HMR Yes, see this: https://www.infoq.com/articles/cs8-ranges-and-recursive-patterns

Answer (score 117):

[With C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges):

```
int[] array = { 1, 3, 5 };
var lastItem = array[^1]; // 5
```

Comment: Requires C# 8 and .Net Framework 4.8 or .Net Core 3. https://github.com/ashmind/SharpLab/issues/390

Answer (score 17):

New in C# 8.0 you can use the so-called "hat" (^) operator! This is useful for when you want to do something in one line!

```cs
var mystr = "Hello World!";
var lastword = mystr.Split(" ")[^1];
Console.WriteLine(lastword);
// World!
```

instead of the old way:

```cs
var mystr = "Hello World";
var split = mystr.Split(" ");
var lastword = split[split.Length - 1];
Console.WriteLine(lastword);
// World!
```

It doesn't save much space, but it looks much clearer (maybe I only think this because I came from python?). This is also much better than calling a method like `.Last()` or `.Reverse()` [Read more at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

Edit: You can add this functionality to your class like so:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
  public object this[Index indx]
  {
    get
    {
      // Do indexing here, this is just an example of the .IsFromEnd property
      if (indx.IsFromEnd)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Negative Index!")
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Positive Index!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `Index.IsFromEnd` will tell you if someone is using the 'hat' (^) operator

Answer (score 8):

Use [Array.GetUpperBound(0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx). [Array.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) contains the number of items in the array, so reading Length -1 only works on the assumption that the array is zero based.

Comment: Aren't all arrays in C# zero based?

Comment: @mgttlinger, most of them are, but you can create non-zero-based arrays with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx, or you may experience them when communicating with libraries written in other languages.

Comment: Awesome! Why isn't this up-voted (it's up to 3 with my vote at the time of this comment)? It's by far the most elegant, non-LINQ solution.

Comment: UPDATE: The GetUpperBound(0) function will only return an `int`. It may not return what the user expects for other numerical arrays, and not all for non-numerical arrays. That's why this isn't up-voted past 3.

Answer (score 5):

To compute the index of the last item:

```
int index = array.Length - 1;
```

Will get you -1 if the array is empty - you should treat it as a special case.

To access the last index:

```
array[array.Length - 1] = ...
```

or

```
... = array[array.Length - 1]
```

will cause an exception if the array is actually empty (Length is 0).

Answer (score 4):

Also, starting with .NET Core 3.0 (and .NET Standard 2.1) (C# 8) you can use `Index` type to keep array's indexes from end:

```cs
var lastElementIndexInAnyArraySize = ^1;
var lastElement = array[lastElementIndexInAnyArraySize];
```

You can use this index to get last array value in any length of array. For example:

```cs
var firstArray = new[] {0, 1, 1, 2, 2};
var secondArray = new[] {3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};
var index = ^1;
var firstArrayLastValue = firstArray[index]; // 2
var secondArrayLastValue = secondArray[index]; // 5
```

For more information check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemindex)

Comment: More on indices - A special value ^0 reduces to length of an array. So firstArray[^0] gives 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' exception!

Answer (score 3):

The following will return NULL if the array is empty, else the last element.

```
var item = (arr.Length == 0) ? null : arr[arr.Length - 1]
```

Comment: This could also be written as `var item = (arr.Length == 0) ?? arr[arr.Length - 1]`.

Comment: @user215361 No, that is invalid C#. Your example will result in: `error CS0019: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'`

Answer (score 3):

This is simplest and works on all versions.

```
int[] array = { 1, 3, 5 };
int last = array[array.Length - 1];
Console.WriteLine(last);
// 5
```

Answer (score 2):

say your array is called arr

do

```
arr[arr.Length - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this worth mentioning?

```
var item = new Stack(arr).Pop();
```

Comment: No. No it does not.

Comment: StilI not slow enough, what about converting into xml and evaluating on sql server?

Answer (score 0):

Array starts from index 0 and ends at n-1.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int length = arr.Length - 1;   // starts from 0 to n-1

    Console.WriteLine(length);     // this will give the last index.
    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int size = 6;
        int[] arr = new int[6] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("The last element is {0}", GetLastArrayIndex(arr));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    //Get Last Index
    static int GetLastArrayIndex(int[] arr)
    {
        try
        {
            int lastNum;
            lastNum = arr.Length - 1;
            return lastNum;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```