# Get the first and last item of an array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays

If I have the following array of strings:

```
string[] stringArray = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

Is there a way to get the first and last item ("one", "four") in C# from the array, besides using array indexing (stringArray[0], stringArray[3]), something like stringArray.First and stringArray.Last ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use indexing?

Comment: i am just curios if there is another way, if it's not I will use indexing, with no problem

Comment: You can use linq but still getting it with index is better (usually you would use array.Length not 3 for last)

Comment: Use indexing when you have the luxury of a string array with indexing available. First() and Last() have to loop over the array and are less performant.

Comment: @Scott, First() and Last() aren't really less performant; for an IList<T> as the source Linq will optimize and use indexing anyway

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use LINQ [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) and [Last()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) methods.

Moreover, both methods have useful overload which allows specifying boolean condition for elements to be considered as first or last.

Answer (score 13):

```
string[] stringArray = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
var last=stringArray.Last();
var first=stringArray.First();
```

Answer (score 7):

There are `stringArray.First()` and `stringArray.Last()` as extension methods in the System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 7):

Different ways to get the **first** index from the array:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(stringArray.First());
Console.WriteLine(stringArray.ElementAt(0));
Console.WriteLine(stringArray[0]);
var stringEnum = stringArray.GetEnumerator();
if (stringEnum.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(stringEnum.Current);
```

Different ways to get the **last** index from the array:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(stringArray.Last());
if (stringArray.Any())
    Console.WriteLine(stringArray.ElementAt(stringArray.Count()-1));
Console.WriteLine(stringArray[stringArray.Length -1]);
var stringEnum = stringArray.GetEnumerator();
string lastValue = null;
while (stringEnum.MoveNext())
    lastValue = (string)stringEnum.Current;
Console.WriteLine(lastValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`stringArray.GetUpperBound(0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound) to get the index of the last item.