# Get the first and last cell in each row of CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8
9,10
```

How can I get the first and last cell to get the file like this:

```
1,5
6,8
9,10
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? You mentioned first and last cell but I see your intended result different

Comment: I want the result like that. Sorry I can't describe in words.

Comment: Now I understand after the editing.... This means you want the first and last cell value on each row

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387396/get-the-first-and-last-item-of-an-array-of-strings This will give you an idea

Comment: Take a look at `string.split` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code that you may use to achieve your goal:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FirstLast
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String file = "C:\\samplec#programs\\FirstLast\\FirstLast\\bin\\Debug\\Test.csv";           

            using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                while (!SR.EndOfStream) //best way to do it
                {
                    //read a line of our file and split it into its separate values
                    var CSValues = SR.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    String first = CSValues.First();
                    String last = CSValues.Last();
                    Console.WriteLine("First val: " + first + " , Last  val: " + last);                    
                }    
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple sample in console, I believe you can understand from here. Take note of

```
String first = CSValues.First();
String last = CSValues.Last();
```